# Checking for an item in a listbox in a array

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub PopulatingArray()
    'Declare the array as a variant array
    Dim groupA() As Variant
    'Declare the integer to store the number of rows
    Dim iRw As Integer
   'Assign range to a the array variable
    groupA = Range("AA1:AA132")
   'loop through the rows - 1 to 10
    For iRw = 1 To UBound(groupA)
        'show the result in the immediate window
        Debug.Print groupA(iRw, 1)
     Next iRw

End Sub

For Each person In ListBox2.Items
    If (groupA.Contains(People)) Then
        MsgBox ("Lets Go")
    End If
Next person
```

Comment: In VBA, an array is a simple datatype, not an object and therefore cannot have any method. You will need to loop over the array manually (as you do in the populating routine). For large amounts of data, you might think about using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is on the userform that contains the listbox, give this a go.  A test procedure will run when you open the form.

```
Option Explicit' not required, but good practice

'Declare the array as a variant array
Dim groupA() As Variant ' mus be before all subs in module

Sub PopulatingArray()
    'Declare the integer to store the number of rows
    Dim iRw As Integer
   'Assign range to a the array variable
    groupA = Range("AA1:AA132")
   'loop through the rows - 1 to 10
    For iRw = 1 To UBound(groupA)
        'show the result in the immediate window
        Debug.Print groupA(iRw, 1)
     Next iRw
End Sub

Sub check_array()
    Dim person As Variant
    For Each person In ListBox2.List
        If contains(groupA, person) Then
            MsgBox ("Lets Go " & person)
        End If
    Next person

End Sub

Function contains(arr As Variant, value As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(x, 1) = value Then
          contains = True
          Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    PopulatingArray
    check_array
End Sub
```